# Stream video with videojs

Tags: video.js

I use videojs and hls to stream video. The .m3u8 loading is found but I have this error. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain/course/9/154' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://domain/public/storage/course_154_9/lesson_55/enc.key'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the browser is blocking an http URL because the page is https. The http URL is `http://domain/public/storage/course_154_9/lesson_55/enc.key` which looks like an AES key which will be listed inside the m3u8 playlists of your HLS stream. You need to make sure your HLS contains only https URLs.